# ASP.Net binding attributes of a custom control's inner property

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, nested

I have created a UserControl with an Inner Property called "Actions", which is a List of "Action" objects. The code looks like this:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
public class MyLink : UserControl
{
    readonly List<Action> _actions = new List<Action>();

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public List<Action> Actions
    {
        get { return _actions; }
    }

    public string Text { get;set; }
    public string Url { get;set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //Build link
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"
            <table class=""myLink"">
                <tr>
                    <td class=""myLinkLeft""><a href=" + Url + @">" + Text + @"</a></td>
                    <td class=""myLinkRight " + MenuName + @"_trigger"">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ");

        //Build actions
        sb.Append("<ul id=\"" + MenuName + "_actions\" class=\"contextMenu\">");

        foreach (Action action in _actions)
        {
            sb.Append("<li class=\"" + action.CssClass + "\"><a href=\"#" + action.Url + "\">" + action.Text + "</a></li>");
        }

        sb.Append("</ul>");

        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}

public class Action : UserControl
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
}
```

If I then put this code in my aspx inside a DataRepeater, it works fine:

```
<uc1:MyLink runat="server" Url="/" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>' MenuName="contextMenu" id="contextMenu">
    <Actions>
        <uc1:Action runat="server" Url="http://mysite.com" Text="MyUrl"  />
        <uc1:Action runat="server" Url="http://google.com" Text="Google" />
    </Actions>
</uc1:MyLink>
```

However, if I try to bind data to the attributes of the Action elements like so:

```
<uc1:MyLink runat="server" Url="/" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>' MenuName="contextMenu" id="contextMenu">
    <Actions>
        <uc1:Action runat="server" Url='<%#DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent).DataItem,"Url") %>' Text="MyUrl"  />
        <uc1:Action runat="server" Url="http://google.com" Text="Google" />
    </Actions>
</uc1:MyLink>
```

I merely get the actual text "<%#DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent).DataItem,"Url") %>" assigned to the Url property, and not the evaluated server expression as I expected.

I've googled this for hours but cannot seem to find anybody else trying to do this. Any ideas why this isn't working and how to get around it?

Thanks,
Bjoern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using tokens for the innermost databinding and then handling the replacement in my control on bind. So the ASPX code looks like this:

```
<uc1:MyLink runat="server" Url="/">
   <Actions>
      <uc1:Action Url="/Page.aspx?cpr=##cpr##&opgaveId=##id##" />
      <uc1:Action Url="/Test.aspx" />
   </Actions>
</uc1:MyLink>
```

And the added CS code like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    DataBinding += BindData;
}

public void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyLink pl = (MyLink) sender;
    IDataItemContainer container = (IDataItemContainer) pl.NamingContainer;
    foreach (Action action in _actions)
    {
        action.Url = ReplaceTokens(action.Url, container);
        action.Text = ReplaceTokens(action.Text, container);
    }
}

private static string ReplaceTokens(string text, IDataItemContainer container)
{
    Regex re = new Regex("##.*?##", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    foreach (Match m in re.Matches(text))
    {
        string tokenValue = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(container.DataItem, m.Value.Substring(2, m.Value.Length - 4), "{0}");
        sb.Replace(m.Value, tokenValue);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the DataRepeater.Datasource in your aspx to a collection or a list static or get from database ...

instead of using DataRepeater try to make a loop inside that list you re already must create it and create new dynamic Action and that in page_load or page_init

```
Action a;
foreach(object x in objects)
{
   a= new Action();
   a.Url = ... ;
   a.Text = ... ;
   MyLink.Actions.Add(a);
}
```

Regards

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, sorry. I solved it myself and I'll post the answer here.